# Facebook callback url is not being called

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, webhooks

i have created facebook callback url with verify token. it sent request and got verified but when i try to send message from webhooks test messages or sendging message to facebook page, it does not send any post request to my server. what i'm misssing?. if i  try to send request from postman it works perfectly. i'm using ngrok to test bot messages to facebook page.

[image]

Comment: _"it does not send any post request to my server"_ - how exactly have you verified that?

Comment: @CBroe no new request have showed in ngrok panel or terminal where i have server running. any other request are showing.